# jQuery ajax script can read first XML file but can't the second one

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

So i have two functions that are similar and should both work, but instead only one of them does.

I have a two xml files from PrestaShop API that i need to get info from. The first one is product names, which works just fine, the second one is for IDs, which does not work even though it's almost the same as the other one.

Code that works for getting product names based on entered product name:

```
delay(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: pageurl+"api/products/?display=[name]&filter[name]=%[" + $("#product_name").text() + "]%",
            dataType: "xml",
            username: key,
            password: "",
            contentType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                var $xml = $(xml);
                $("#product_names").html("");
                $xml.find('product').each(function () {
                    var choice = $(this).find('language[id="1"]').text();
                    $("#product_names").append("<option value=\""+choice+"\">");
                });
            }
        });
    }, 700);
```

Here's the XML file this function is reading:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <products>
        <product>
            <name>
                <language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/wogshop/api/languages/1">
                    <![CDATA[ Nice Dress ]]>
                </language>
                <language id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost/wogshop/api/languages/2">
                    <![CDATA[ Nice Dress ]]>
                </language>
            </name>
        </product>
    </products>
</prestashop>
```

And this is the code that cannot read the XML file:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pageurl+"api/products/?display=[id]&filter[name]=[" + $("#product_name").text() + "]",
        dataType: "xml",
        username: key,
        password: "",
        contentType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var real_id;

            real_id = $(xml).find('id').text();

            $("#product_id").val(real_id);
            $("#bananas").html("ID is "+$(xml).text());
        }
    });
```

Here's the XML file it's looking at if i search for "Printed Dress":

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>
                <![CDATA[ 3 ]]>
            </id>
        </product>
    </products>
</prestashop>
```

I have no clue why it's not working. It looks like it should work but yet it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i fixed it myself. Everything started working when i changed `$("#product_name").text()` in the URL to `$("#product_name").val()`. In short, changed `.text()` to `.val()`.